# Modify props.value from within child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue and trying to build a "dropdown" component. I want to use it from a parent component like this:

```
<my-dropdown v-model="selection"></my-dropdown>
```

where `selection` is stored as `data` on the parent, and should be updated to reflect the user's selection. To do this I believe my dropdown component needs a `value` prop and it needs to emit `input` events when the selection changes.

However, I also want to modify the `value` from within the child itself, because I want to be able to use the dropdown component on its own (I need to modify it because otherwise the UI will not update to reflect the newly selected value if the component is used on its own).

Is there a way I can bind with `v-model` as above, but also modify the value from within the child (it seems I can't, because `value` is a prop and the child can't modify its own props).

Comment: You can't modify a prop in anyway, but you can setup a mirror data inside the component, and use that data to update UI while there're no `v-model` passed to it.

Comment: @wxsm how should I mirror it? The problem I'm having is parent changes selection > child detects prop change and updates data > child emits event 
 because data changed > parent detects event and updates selection and the cycle just repeats infinitely.

Comment: Read up on the sync modifier: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: @btl I'm not really sure how that helps me, because in that example the state seems to live on the parent only.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have a computed property proxy for a local value that handles the input/value values.

```
props: {
  value: {
    required: true,
  }
},
computed: {
  mySelection: {
    get() {
      return this.value;
    },
    set(v) {
      this.$emit('input', v)
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can set your template to use the `mySelection` value for managing your data inside this component and as it changes, the data is emitted correctly and is always in sync with the v-model (`selected`) when you use it in the parent.

Comment: @Ferrybig you're right. It should emit `v`. My mistake. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This assumes I have a parent component to receive the event and update the prop.

Comment: @Flash aren’t you using this component within another?

Comment: How is this not the top answer? it solves the original issue in the most elegant way possible with a very clean, reusable pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify a prop inside a component, I recommend passing a "default value" prop to your component. Here is how I would do that

```
<MyDropdownComponent
  :default="defaultValue"
  :options="options"
  v-model="defaultValue"
/>
```

And then there are 2 options to how I would go from there -

### Option 1 - custom dropdown element

As you're using custom HTML, you won't be able to set a selected attribute. So you'll need to be creative about your methods.
Inside your component, you can set the default value `prop` to a data attribute on component creation. You may want to do this differently, and use a `watcher` instead. I've added that to the example below.

```
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.selected = this.default;
  },
  methods: {
    // This would be fired on change of your dropdown.
    // You'll have to pass the `option` as a param here,
    // So that you can send  that data back somehow
    myChangeMethod(option) {
      this.$emit('input', option);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    default() {
      this.selected = this.default;
    },
  },
};
```

The `$emit` will pass the data back to the parent component, which won't have been modified. You won't need to do this if you're using a standard `select` element.

### Option 2 - Standard `select`

```
<template>
  <select
    v-if="options.length > 1"
    v-model="value"
    @change="myChangeMethod"
  >
    <option
      v-for="(option, index) of options"
      :key="option.name"
      :value="option"
      :selected="option === default"
    >{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // This would be fired on change of your dropdown
    myChangeMethod() {
      this.$emit('input', this.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This method is definitely the easiest, and means you need to use the default `select` element.

Comment: In both options, you are missing the ability to react to the condition when the parent updates the value for some reason

Comment: @Ferrybig Actually in the second option, the value will update :) The first example would require a `watcher`, which I mentioned
Edit: Oops! I didn't emit the correct value!

Comment: See my comment above: the problem I'm having is parent changes selection > child detects prop change and updates data > child emits event because data changed > parent detects event and updates selection and the cycle just repeats infinitely

Comment: @Flash please recreate an example, and I can help take a look :)

Answer (score 3):

Vue's philosophy is: "**props down, events up**".  It even says this in the documentation: [Composing Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components).

> Components are meant to be used together, most commonly in
> parent-child relationships: component A may use component B in its own
> template. They inevitably need to communicate to one another: the
> parent may need to pass data down to the child, and the child may need
> to inform the parent of something that happened in the child. However,
> it is also very important to keep the parent and the child as
> decoupled as possible via a clearly-defined interface. This ensures
> each component’s code can be written and reasoned about in relative
> isolation, thus making them more maintainable and potentially easier
> to reuse.
>
> In Vue, the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as
> **props down, events up**. The parent passes data down to the child via
> props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events. Let’s
> see how they work next.

Don't try to modify the value from within the child component.  Tell the parent component about something and, if the parent cares, it can do something about it.  Having the child component change things gives too much responsibility to the child.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom form input component

[Form Input Components using Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

Basically your custom component should accept a `value` prop and emit `input` event when value changes

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following pattern:

1. Accept 1 input prop
2. Have another variable inside your data
3. On creation, white the incoming prop into your data variable
4. Using a watcher, watch the incoming prop for changes
5. On a change inside your component, send the change away

Demo:

```js
'use strict';
Vue.component('prop-test', {
  template: "#prop-test-template",
  props: {
    value: { // value is the default prop used by v-model
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dataObject: undefined,
      // For testing purposes:
      receiveData: true,
      sendData: true,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.dataObject = this.value;
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      // `If` is only here for testing purposes
      if(this.receiveData)
      this.dataObject = this.value;
    },
    dataObject() {
      // `If` is only here for testing purposes
      if(this.sendData)
      this.$emit('input', this.dataObject);
    },
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: 'c',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.1/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="prop-test-template">
  <fieldset>
    <select v-model="dataObject">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
      <option value="d">d</option>
      <option value="e">e</option>
      <option value="f">f</option>
      <option value="g">g</option>
      <option value="h">h</option>
      <option value="i">i</option>
      <option value="j">j</option>
    </select>
    <!-- For testing purposed only: -->
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="receiveData">
      Receive updates
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="sendData">
      Send updates
    </label>
    <!--/ For testing purposed only: -->
  </fieldset>
</script>
<div id="app">
  <prop-test v-model="test"></prop-test>
  <prop-test v-model="test"></prop-test>
  <prop-test v-model="test"></prop-test>
</div>
```

Notice that this demo has a feature that you can turn off the propagation of the events per select box, so you can test if the values are properly updated locally, this is of course not needed for production.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @zero298's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751374/345716) this time for Vue3, the Vue3 Guide [explicity](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props) calls out it being a best practice for components not to modify (the insides of) props:

> **Mutating Object / Array Props​**
>
> When objects and arrays are passed as props, while the child component cannot mutate the prop binding, it will be able to mutate the object or array's nested properties. This is because in JavaScript objects and arrays are passed by reference, and it is unreasonably expensive for Vue to prevent such mutations.
>
> The main drawback of such mutations is that it allows the child component to affect parent state in a way that isn't obvious to the parent component, potentially making it more difficult to reason about the data flow in the future. As a best practice, you should avoid such mutations unless the parent and child are tightly coupled by design. In most cases, the child should emit an event to let the parent perform the mutation.

So even though it is *possible*, it is not *best practice*. `$emit` events with the new value instead, and let the parent modify it's own state.