# Multiple child values in parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I currently have a parent component that has 2 children.

Both the children are simple `<input>` fields

In my parent, I have a button (this a form afterall), when click, I'd like to get the values of both children in my parent, so I can send it to an API endpoint.

Whats the easiest way?

I've seen `props` and `$emit` but not sure which is the best approach

Thanks

EDIT:

My parent looks like following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <name-filter></name-filter>
    <report-type-filter></report-type-filter>
    <button @click="sumbmitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NameFilter from './filters/NameFilter.vue';
  import ReportTypeFilter from './filters/ReportTypeFilter.vue';

  export default{
    components: {
        NameFilter,
        ReportTypeFilter
    },
    data() {
        return {
            name: "",
            type: ""
        };
    },

    methods: {
        sumbmitForm() {
            // I'd like to get the <input> values here
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify props.value from within child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575226/modify-props-value-from-within-child-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want exactly so i'm assuming that your code looks like this:

```
<form>
     <input>
     <input>
     <button>
</form>
```

If that's the case, then you can use v-model on both inputs to get their values like this:

```
<form>
    <input v-model="input1">
    <input v-model="input2">
    <button>
</form>
```

Then, define those two variable inside your data:

```
data() {
     return {
          input1: '',
          input2: '',
     }
}
```

This will give you the ability to get their values like this: **this.input1** and **this.input2**